# Cannot Retrieve a Share URL

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api, file-sharing

All I'm trying is to to get a link for sharing the uploaded file.

I send the POST request to this URL:

api.dropbox.com/1/shares/auto/my_text_file.txt?all_the_oauth1_stuff...

But I always receive the 401 not authorized error.

I'm kinda following the documentation, so could anyone explain what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: If you're getting a 401, then presumably the issue is the auth, and you haven't shown us anything about how you're doing auth. Is there a reason you have to use OAuth 1? Are you using HMAC-SHA256 or PLAINTEXT? Without sharing the OAuth token, maybe you can tell us what query parameters you're using and what SDK (if any) you're using.

Comment: @smarx, thanks for your time. This is how it actually looks like (key, token and signature removed):

https://api.dropbox.com/1/shares/auto/my_text_file.txt?oauth_consumer_key=my_key&oauth_nonce=2722486&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1419246329&oauth_token=token&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=signature

And, I'm using this http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/csharp/OAuthBase.cs

Comment: @smarx, And one more thing. I use the same signing method for download / upload and it works fine for both cases. It only fails on shares

Comment: @smarx, I solved it. Something else was causing the issue. Read the answer below. Thanks again. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was occurring because of the wrong encoding of the file name (which worked for download / upload scenarios)